# how to change header toplinks names in magento 1?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.9

I have this static header toplink with 4 links: My account, My cart, checkout, login.

I want to change the names and the ahrefs of these 4 links, how can I do this?

This is my header.phtml file:

```
<div class="header-container">

<div class="topbar">
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topLinks') ?>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topSearch') ?>
</div>

<div class="header">
    <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" class="logo"><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/logo.png'); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" /></a>

    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topMenu') ?>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topCart'); ?>

    <?php if(Mage::getModel('cms/block')->load('header-notice')->getIsActive() == "1") { ?>

        <div class="notice">
            <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('header-notice')->toHtml(); ?>
        </div>

    <?php } ?>

    <?php //echo $this->getChildHtml('topContainer'); ?>        
</div>
```

And this is my links.phtml file

```
    <?php $_links = $this->getLinks(); ?>
<?php if(count($_links)>0): ?>
<ul class="links"<?php if($this->getName()): ?> id="<?php echo $this->getName() ?>"<?php endif;?>>
    <?php foreach($_links as $_link): ?>
        <?php if ($_link instanceof Mage_Core_Block_Abstract):?>
            <?php echo $_link->toHtml() ?>
        <?php else: ?>
            <li<?php if($_link->getIsFirst()||$_link->getIsLast()): ?> class="<?php if($_link->getIsFirst()): ?>first<?php endif; ?><?php if($_link->getIsLast()): ?> last<?php endif; ?>"<?php endif; ?> <?php echo $_link->getLiParams() ?>><?php echo $_link->getBeforeText() ?><a href="<?php echo $_link->getUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $_link->getTitle() ?>" <?php echo $_link->getAParams() ?>><?php echo $_link->getLabel() ?></a><?php echo $_link->getAfterText() ?></li>
        <?php endif;?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: https://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-edit-header-links-2.html#gref

Answer (score 0):

It very simple to change top links title and links.

1. For Myaccount, login, , register change in customer.xml
2. For cart change in checkout.xml

Path for these files if you are using RWD theme: app\design\frontend\rwd\default\layout

Thats All !!!